# Why does an error occur when I pass a ' View ' object returned by ' findViewById() ' to addView() of LinearLayout class, as parameter?

Tags: java, android

The code is below... It's of main Activity class of an android project. I have compiled it as well as created a `.apk` file using debug mode in '`ant`' and installed it on my android device.
When I ran the installed app, an error message displayed :

> Unfortunately app1 has stooped working

**Main_Activity Class**

```
    package arkk.app1;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.view.*;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.*;

    public class Main_Activity extends Activity
    {
        TextView tV;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LinearLayout v=new LinearLayout(this);
            Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Button button2=new Button(this);
            tV=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            v.addView(tV);
            v.addView(button1);
            v.addView(button2,new               
            LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            setContentView(v);
        }
        public void actionPerformed(View view) {
            tV.setText("Button1");

        }
    }
```

Every thing is fine (the app runs on my device) if the lines 19 ( `v.addView(tV)` ) and 20 ( `v.addView(button1)` ) are commented out.

However if I compile and run the app on my device(android kitkat) without commenting lines 19 and 20 the above mentioned error occurs.

So what I figured out is that the lines 19 and 20 are causing the error, but couldn't figure out why........

I have just started learning android programming and am using ' `Apache ant` ' to build my projects with the help of command prompt.
I've checked the documentation of `LinearLayout class` on this site :   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

From it I was able to verify that '`addView(View view)`' is a method of `View class` and `LinearLayout extends View`.

So now I am at my wit's end what's the problem in this code. I guess a **runtime exception is occurring?...** but that's just a guess...

Thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: It's probably due to the view already been added but - please post the logcat describing the crash. Unfortunatelly, you telling us that "app has stopped working" doesn't reveal anything about the crash nor helps us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find views using findViewById, you have to either inflate the view or call setContentView on the main View that contains them.

Simply call setContentView(R.layout.your_activity) after calling super in onCreate. your_activity would be the xml file for that activity.

```
        Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

In the above line, findViewById does not know which view it has to search in to find button1. This is because setContentView is called after this line. So you either have to call setContentView for the containing view before that

**OR**

Alternatively, inflate the view and call findViewById on that view.

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.your_activity, null);
Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(...);
tV=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: does it mean that view objects declared in xml layout cannot be treated as those view objects which are declared programmatically..?

Comment: No, they are the same and can be treated the same. The only thing that you have to keep in mind is that you absolutely cannot access the objects which you put in an xml without inflating the resource first. setContentView inflates the view before showing it. The other way would be inflating it manually as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: To add more details, xml only holds attributes not objects. When you call findViewById, Android looks for an object that has been already drawn. So a View object has to be created first by inflating the View where it belongs.  Otherwise, if it is not yet drawn, it will be return null. That is essentially what setContentView does. It draws the objects in your layout file so that you can access them later.

Answer (score 0):

Well... after acting upon the suggestions of  **SoroushA** and doing a bit more research I found out that the exception that was being thrown by **`v.addView(tV)`** (line 19) and **`v.addView(button1)`**(line 20) is `IllegalStateException` which caused the app to crash. 
Modified code is below

```
    package arkk.app1;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.view.*;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.*;

    public class Main_Activity extends Activity
    {
        TextView tV;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            LinearLayout v=new LinearLayout(this);

            View vCustom =                                 
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main, null);
            Button button1=(Button) vCustom.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Button button2=new Button(this);
            tV=(TextView) vCustom.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            try {
                v.addView(tV);
                v.addView(button1);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                button2.setText(e.toString());
            }

            v.addView(button2,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            setContentView(v);

        }
        public void actionPerformed(View view) {
            tV.setText("Button1");

        }
    }
```

This Exception was thrown because `textView` and `button1` are already children of `LinearLayout` View which came into existance after being inflated by the line -  
`View vCustom = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.main, null);`
When we attempt to add these two views to a new parent(or container)  **v** an `IllegalStateException` occurs.

I have displayed the output on a button(button2) and used try-catch statements to catch the exception and display it on the button